Cannot navigate through (JSON)-object / response from API call - it doesn't behave the same way in JavaScript and Nuxt 3
I have the following example-response from an REST-API call, let's call it "A":
{
  "data": {
    "id": 2,
    "email": "janet.weaver@reqres.in",
    "first_name": "Janet",
    "last_name": "Weaver",
    "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"
  },
  "support": {
    "url": "https://reqres.in/#support-heading",
    "text": "To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"
  }
}

If I enter the following in the Google Chrome console, I can navigate through the object as shown below:
test = A

console.log(test.data.id)
-> 2

But if I now try to do the same in my Nuxt 3 (index.vs), I cannot navigate through the result:
<template>
  <div>
        {{ test }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: []
    };
  },
  async created() {
    try {      
      //this response doesn't work - but I need this
      const test = await useFetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')

      //this response works
      //const test = '{"data":{"id":2,"email":"janet.weaver@reqres.in","first_name":"Janet","last_name":"Weaver","avatar":"https://reqres.in/img/faces/2-image.jpg"},"support":{"url":"https://reqres.in/#support-heading","text":"To keep ReqRes free, contributions towards server costs are appreciated!"}}'

      this.test = JSON.parse(test).data.id
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>

Why does the first "test" (with useFetch) not work?
I tried to debug it and created the smallest possible example so that somebody who understands Javascript and/or Nuxt 3 can help me. I am very grateful for any help!

aren't you missing    const data = await test.json();  after your fetch?

useFetch creates no response object, so json() isn't a valid method for this.

I found the solution by watching this video:
useFetch, useLazyfetch with Nuxt 3 — Course part 14 by Codewithguillaume
The solution is:
const { data } = await useFetch('https://reqres.in/api/users/2')

console.log((data.value).data.id)

